# Lavavel 5: Error page middlewares are not accessible

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm using `Laravel 5.0` and getting one issue. My site is working fine when there is no error like 404, 500 etc. But when there is error on my site then it render error page but some middlewares are not loading.

My site has two parts frontend and backend. Both parts have diff-diff middlewares which I'm using. I'm using some number of custom middlewares, some of them I'm using on frontend and some of them using on backend. But when there is any error on site then middlewares are not working which are loaded in `$routeMiddleware` array in Kernel.php file.

I research number of articles but all gives me same solution to load all required middlewares in `$middleware`, which seems not fine to me. Because in `$middleware` array all middlewares are loading for both fronend and backend sections. But I need to load spacial middlewares only single section. How could I implement this.

This is my kernel.php file

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel {
   /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
        'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
        'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
        // 'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
        'auth.frontend' => 'App\Http\Middleware\FrontendAuthenticate',
        'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
    ];
}
```

And this is my route.php file code

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth.frontend'], function() {
    Route::get('/home', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
    Route::get('/inner_page', ['as' => 'inner_page', 'uses' => 'HomeController@inner_page']);
});
```

How this is possible, please help me on this issue.

Comment: Please provide your `Kernel.php` middlewares snippet + `routes.php` for clarity

Comment: OK, now just one question, do you want to run a **middleware** when the response HTTP code is an error in general? or when a specific route is requested and server returns an error?

Comment: @RaminOmrani Yes, I want to run middlewear when response HTTP code is an error and also only for my frontend section.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#terminable-middleware), you must define a `terminate($request, $response)` method to run the middle-ware after the response is ready to be sent to the browser. The `terminate($request, $response)` method should receive both the request and the response.

then you can either add your **middle-ware** to the `global` or `route` middle-ware arrays.

**example :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class FrontendAuthenticate
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    public function terminate($request, $response)
    {
        // Check if the $response is an error and then do stuff 
    }
}
```

Comment: I did. but still same.. I use debuging in handle() as well as in terminate() function of FrontendAuthenticate but no effect. Actually control is not comming on FrontendAuthenticate.

Comment: @LuckySaini, What type of error do **Laravel** generate when you request to `FrontendAuthenticate`? Why should a defined route return 400 or 500 HTTP code?